# Having issues setting up the view model for my webpage

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, web

```js
function npCinemaViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.movies = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "3 Days to Kill", url: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/vf49ZETvNaQ" },
    { name: "Endless Love", url: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/5paHdmfFNS8" },
    { name: "Robocop", url: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/xPLSpmAtc1Q" },
    { name: "Lego Movie", url: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/fZ_JOBCLF-I" }
  ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new npCinemaViewModel());
```

```html
<nav id="movies">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: movies">
    <li><a class="youtube glowButton" data-bind="text: name, attr: {href: url}"></a></li>
    <!--<li><a class="youtube glowButton" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5paHdmfFNS8">Endless Love</a></li>
    <li><a class="youtube glowButton" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xPLSpmAtc1Q">Robocop</a></li>
    <li><a class="youtube glowButton" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fZ_JOBCLF-I">Lego Movie</a></li>-->
  </ul>
```

The data will not appear in the data-bound doms, and I can't quite figure out what the issue is. I have linked the script the same way as my other ones and dev tools show the source .js file is indeed being recognized.  It seems like the viewModel is just not being applied.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you get any console errors? is this code even being run?  Also, show your html binding if you can.  I'm not a knockout pro, but I don't think there's enough here to get a quality answer.

Comment: I am getting an error "cannot read property "nodeType" of null

Comment: Fixed!!! put inside $(document).ready(function(){ ko.applyBindings(new npCinemaViewModel());});

Comment: was gunna say, worked fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/8j4T7/

Comment: I suppose it tries to apply bindings that don't exist yet lol. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to apply the bindings after the document loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  ko.applyBindings(new npCinemaViewModel());
});
```